# Keras freeze specific weights with mask

Tags: keras, convolution, masking

I am new in Keras. I want to implement a layer where not all the weights will update. For example, in the following code, I want the `dilation` layer will update in a way that some center weights are never updated. For say, the shape of each feature matrix (out of 1024) in the `dilation` layer is `448, 448` and a block of `8x8` at the center of all feature matrices will never be updated, i.e. the `8x8` block is a (non-trainable) mask to the feature matrices.

```
input_layer=Input(shape=(896,896,3))
new_layer = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(input_layer)
new_layer = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2), padding='same', data_format=None)(new_layer)
new_layer = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(new_layer)
new_layer = Conv2D(1024, kernel_size=(7,7), dilation_rate=8, padding="same", activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='dialation')(new_layer)
new_layer = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(1,1), padding="same", activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(new_layer)
new_layer = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(1,1), padding="same", activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(new_layer)

model = Model(input_layer, new_layer)
```

I was trying with the Keras's `custom layer`  [[link]](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/), but it was difficult for me to understand. Anyone would please help.

**UPDATE**: 
I added the following figure for a better understanding. The dilation layer contains 1024 features. I want the middle region of each feature to be non-trainable (static).

[image: image of dilation layer]

Comment: Please explain it better. You are mixing weights and features, they are two different things. Do you want the features to be static at some coordinate or do you want the weights to be static at some coordinate? Or do you want that some part of the features do not contribute to the weight update?

Comment: Thanks for your point. I updated the description. I want static weights to the features at some coordinates.

Comment: Just to be sure. Do you understand that the weights are always 7x7 and totally independent of the coordinates in the image? The same 7x7 will be applied ob the entire image.

Comment: A weight is trainable, but a feature is not trainable. That is why I'm confused about what you want. There are a few possibities, though. You can replace the middle of the feature with a constant value. You can stop gradients in the middle of the feature so this part of the  feature does not count in backpropagation (the weights will update nevertheless, the same 7x7 matrix is applied to the entire image).

Comment: This is what I want to implement: "You can replace the middle of the feature with a constant value. You can stop gradients in the middle of the feature so this part of the feature does not count in backpropagation" - could you provide any implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this mask for both cases:

```
mask = np.zeros((1,448,448,1))
mask[:,220:228,220:228] = 1
```

### Replacing part of the feature

If you replace part of the feature with constant values, this means the feature will be static, but it will still participate in backpropagation (because weights will still be multiplied and summed for this part of the image and there is a connection)

```
constant = 0 (will annulate kernel, but not bias) 

def replace(x):
    return x*(1-mask) + constant*mask

#before the dilation layer
new_layer=Lambda(replace)(new_layer)
```

### Keeping the feature value, but stopping backpropagation

Here, the weights of the dilation layer and further will be updated normally, but the weights before the dilation layer will not receive the influence of the central region.

```
def stopBackprop(x):
    stopped=K.stop_gradients(x)
    return x*(1-mask) + stopped*mask

#before the dilation layer
new_layer=Lambda(stopBackprop)(new_layer)
```

Comment: Thank you for the implementation example.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on clustering weights and then freezing specific clusters and train the network.

I am trying to freeze the specific weights in this network using the above example. But I'm not sure how to set the shape of the mask and custom layer in run_certain_weights().

This is the code I'm using:

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Lambda
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy
from keras.backend import stop_gradient
import numpy as np

def load_data():
    
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
    x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
    x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
    x_train /= 255
    x_test /= 255
    y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=10)
    y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=10)
    
    return x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test

def run():
    x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = load_data()

    model=Sequential(Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)))

    layer = Dense(300, name='dense1', activation='relu')
    layer.trainable=True
    model.add(layer)
    layer2 = Dense(100, name='dense2', activation='relu')
    layer2.trainable=False
    model.add(layer2)
    layer3 = Dense(10, name='dense3', activation='softmax')
    model.add(layer3)

    model.compile(loss=categorical_crossentropy, optimizer='Adam',metrics ['accuracy'])


    print(model.summary())
    print("x_train.shape():",x_train.shape)
    print("y_train.shape()",y_train.shape)

    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, verbose=2)
    print(model.evaluate(x_test, y_test))
    
    return model

def stopBackprop(x):
    
    stopped=stop_gradient(x)
    return x*(1-mask) + stopped*mask

def run_certain_weights():
    
    x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = load_data()
    model=Sequential(Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)))
    mask = np.zeros((300,))
    print(mask.shape)
    mask[220:228,] = 1

    layer = Dense(300, name='dense1', activation='relu')
    layer.trainable=False
    model.add(layer)

    #before the dense2 layer
    new_layer=Lambda(stopBackprop)(layer)
    model.add(new_layer)

    layer2 = Dense(300, name='dense2', activation='relu')
    layer2.trainable=True
    model.add(layer2)
    layer3 = Dense(10, name='dense3', activation='softmax')
    model.add(layer3)

    model.compile(loss=categorical_crossentropy, optimizer='Adam',metrics = ['accuracy'])


    print(model.summary())
    print("x_train.shape():",x_train.shape)
    print("y_train.shape()",y_train.shape)

    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, verbose=2)
    print(model.evaluate(x_test, y_test))
    return model


def freeze(model):
    x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = load_data()

    name = 'dense2'

    weightsAndBias = model.get_layer(name=name).get_weights()

    # freeze the weights of this layer
    model.get_layer(name=name).trainable = False

    # record the weights before retrain
    weights_before = weightsAndBias[0]
    # retrain
    print("x_train.shape():",x_train.shape)
    print("y_train.shape()",y_train.shape)

    model.fit(x_train, y_train, verbose=2, epochs=1)
    weights_after = model.get_layer(name=name).get_weights()[0]

    if (weights_before == weights_after).all():
        print('the weights did not change!!!')
    else:
        print('the weights changed!!!!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    model = run()
    freeze(model)

    model = run_certain_weights()
    freeze(model)
```